# How to use friendly_id with a relationship between 2 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, friendly-id

I have 2 relationships that need to be used in 1 model. The error I am getting is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /books/booky-wook    
Couldn't find Gallery with id=booky-wook

def show
    @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am using friendly_id gem to create friendly urls for my posts etc and pages. I am currently running 2 models:

1) Book
2) Gallery

In book I need to call the gallery id to get the gallery that has been attached to the book. Here are the models:

Book.rb

```
has_attached_file :jacket_cover, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :jacket_cover, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

validates :jacket_cover, :title, :slug, :synopsis, :body, :age, :publisher, presence: true

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

belongs_to :author
has_one :gallery

accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery

scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
scope :unavailable, ->{ where(available: [nil, false]) }
```

gallery.rb

```
belongs_to :books
has_many :images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```

books_controller.rb

```
  def show
    # @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @book.build_author
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    @book.build_gallery
  end
```

And in the controller for my book I am trying to retrieve the gallery id but friendly id is stopping it from happening. i have added this to the initializer file for the gem:

config.use :finders

I suppose its a conflicting issue maybe here but its not an an obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
```

of this method

```
  def show
    @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end
```

You are looking to fetch both `Book` and `Gallery` with the same `params[:id]`. Given that this is a `Book`'s route, I am guessing `params[:id]` should be the friendly id of a book.

You need to find the gallery through the book, possibly something like this:

```
@gallery = @book.gallery
```

Comment: Hi Srikanth yes I have managed to come to this and I am now trying figure out how to override it and get the gallery id and not the id of the book which is being used for friendly_id

Comment: Can you not look at getting the book's gallery, via the association?

Comment: yes I have tried that I think, the method you edited above I have also tried that and its throwing `undefined method find`

Comment: could you post exactly what you tried? `@book.gallery` should work, since you have a `has_one` defined.

Comment: I added `@gallery = @book.gallery` and in the show view I put `<%= @gallery.id %>`and it outputted the id which is fine but I need to access the gallery images via `<% @gallery.image.each do |image| %>` and I get the error `undefined method `image' for #<Gallery:0x00000100c55ac0>`

Comment: Hey Srikanth I hope this has not confused you at all :)

Comment: `Gallery` `has_many :images`. Which means, you need to use `@gallery.images.each`. Note that since it is `has_many` you need to pluralize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61363/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-srikanth-venugopalan).